# What encoding does the unicode function in BeautifulSoup convert from?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

When I use the `unicode` function in BeautifulSoup - what encoding does it convert to Unicode from? Does it automatically use the `soup.originalEncoding`?

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
doc = "<html><h1>Heading</h1><p>Text"
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc)
print unicode(soup)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`unicode()` is a Python builtin, not part of BeautifulSoup. See the [docs here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?#unicode).

> **`unicode([object[, encoding[, errors]]])`**
>
> If encoding and/or errors are given,
>   unicode() will decode the object which
>   can either be an 8-bit string or a
>   character buffer using the codec for
>   encoding. The encoding parameter is a
>   string giving the name of an encoding;
>   if the encoding is not known,
>   LookupError is raised. Error handling
>   is done according to errors; this
>   specifies the treatment of characters
>   which are invalid in the input
>   encoding. If errors is 'strict' (the
>   default), a ValueError is raised on
>   errors, while a value of 'ignore'
>   causes errors to be silently ignored,
>   and a value of 'replace' causes the
>   official Unicode replacement
>   character, U+FFFD, to be used to
>   replace input characters which cannot
>   be decoded. See also the codecs
>   module.

If you don't specify the encoding, `sys.getdefaultencoding()` will be used by default.

Comment: Types can override `unicode()` by implementing the special [`__unicode__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__unicode__) method.  If a type implements this method, the `unicode()` builtin simply returns the result of this method, and a type can basically return whatever it wants from this method.  So the result of the call in the OP in fact depends on the implementation of the `BeautifulSoup` class.

Comment: Good point. Does anyone know whether BeautifulSoup overrides the builtin function?